# RadStudio 10.2 Tokyo – глюки в модуле 'vcldesigner250.bpl'

Tags: delphi, компоненты

Есть форма (Delphi), на ней расположена «*TTabSheet*» на которой вместе с другими компонентами находились 4 «*TEdit*».
Форма немного преобразовалась: на форму кинулся «*TGroupBox*» и на него переместились ("Cut -> Paste") эти 4 «*TEdit*» («*edGPU0*», «*edTemp0*», «*edGPU1*», «*edTemp1*») и еще некоторые компоненты.
И получилось так, что при выполнении доступа к ним (во время выполнения программы), например, самых простых:

```
edGPU0.Clear
```

или

```
edGPU1.Clear;
```

у меня выкидывается ошибка:

> … raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at
>   0x005611f8: read of address 0x00000050'.

С другими компонентами «edit» такого не наблюдается.

**Текст dfm** [тут](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfuvo05z4bijmnv/Form1%20%28bad%29.dfm.txt?dl=0)

Если во время проектирования, обратиться к тексту *dfm* («*View as tex*t»), то также валится ошибка:
Error

> Access violation at address 525E0394 in module
>   'vcldesigner250.bpl'. Read of address 00000000.  >>
>   OK   Details>>

Кнопка «*Details >>*» при этом не работает, виснет просто Delphi.

Кто нибудь встречался с такой оказией? И что при этом делать?
P.S.
- У меня есть еще один проект, но там больше компонентов, и опять такая же фигня.

Comment: Вероятно баг IDE/Delphi. Попробуйте использовать другую версию Delphi.

Comment: Поставьте breakpoint. Точно edGPU0 и edGPU1 инициализированы и не равны nil?

Comment: Проект переносили из другой версии? Или вообще форму перетаскивали из другого проекта?

Comment: с "vcldesigner250.bpl", так и не понял как разобраться (иногда при выходе из Delphi он виснет с такой ошибкой- вероятно с сборкой чего не так,). А про "edGPU", оказалось, что я не там делал проверку на nil, Переименовал компонент и забыл, а при обращении к нему строил динамически его имя, при этом компилятор ошибку не находил,

Comment: Покажите объявление типа `TFMain`

Comment: Возможно, вы потеряли в объявлении (в .pas) какой-то из объектов, который есть на форме в .dfm (например `edGPU0`). В XE5 ваша dfm-ка отобразилась без проблем.